# html5 video random pause after 25%

Tags: html, random, html5-video

I Have Question . I can`t to do auto pause . for example , if video is 30 seconds , i need pause after each 5 seconds . sorry for my bad english . And If Video Was not paused to write IP in  console.

Comment: You want to do logging ?

Comment: No man . I Want to do pausing on each 5 seconds from start

Answer (score 0):

If your video has autoplay and controls, you could do something like this (UNTESTED):

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var nextPause = 5;
video.ontimeupdate = function() {
  if (video.currentTime >= nextPause) {
    video.pause();
    nextPause += 5;
  }
};
```

The video will play until about 5 seconds in, then pause. The user can press play to have it continue playing, and it will stop at about 10 seconds. Etc.

Is that what you're looking for?